# Send in HTML/components to composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

How can achieve this for my composite component?

Simple example: when using my component:

`<my:myComponent>
    html code and other components
</my:myComponent>`

my composite component implementation:

`<composite:implementation>
   <div>
      <!-- inject html code and other components here -->
   </div>
</composite:implementation>`

Can I use decorate somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<composite:implementation>
   <div>
       <composite:insertChildren/>
   </div>
</composite:implementation>
```